# Android Facebook SDK 4.0.1: How to get number of invites sent back from AppInviteDialog

Tags: android, facebook

Does anybody know if there's any way to get the number of invites sent back from the new FB AppInviteDialog? I'm able to get an AppInviteDialog.Result, but it doesn't seem to contain any useful information.

Here's my code:

```
public static void openDialogInvite(final Activity activity)
{
    String appLinkUrl, previewImageUrl;

    appLinkUrl = "your app link url";
    previewImageUrl = "https://www.example.com/my_invite_image.jpg";

    if (AppInviteDialog.canShow())
    {
        AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
                .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
                .build();

        AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(activity);
        appInviteDialog.registerCallback(sCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel()
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e)
            {
            }
        });

        appInviteDialog.show(content);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to know that?

Comment: @WizKid For our internal analytics. We'd like to know how effective the AppInviteDialog is.

Comment: Track how many users actually come to your app through the requests instead.

Comment: We do, but that's only half the equation of determining the effectiveness of the app invite (effectiveness = new users / requests sent)

Comment: How many that is sent doesn't matter. You can't effect the number of invites sent anyway so the interesting part is new users / invite dialog opens

Comment: It actually does matter to us. We actually might want to compare the effectiveness of FB invites vs other means.

Comment: The answer is still that you can't

Comment: @WizKid Can you show any proof that it's not possible? Also, to make sure you guys talk about the same thing I'm searching: I'm trying to get the number of people that got app-invites from here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android . Is this what you guys ask about too?

Comment: This question is 2 years old, did you manage to find a way to measure the amount of invites?

Comment: No, this was never solved.